# restart force stopped app on receiving sms

Tags: android

I am trying to restart my app on receiving sms if it is force stopped. This is my code.
Its not restarting the app.Should I try writing receiver as another class.
      In manifest  :

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <receiver android:name=".MySMSbr"> 
     <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
     </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 

 My mainActivity onCreate() :

   private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
BroadcastReceiver SMSbr;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in OnCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
     SMSbr = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {

          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) 
          {
              this.abortBroadcast();
              Toast.makeText(context, "in onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
                        AppSettings.getLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this));
              this.clearAbortBroadcast();
            }//end of onReceive method

          };//end of BroadcastReceiver

          IntentFilter SMSfilter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
          this.registerReceiver(SMSbr, SMSfilter);
  }
    in togglelogging the service is started
    where is it going wrong.
```

Comment: AFAIK, force stopped apps cannot be restarted by `Intent` on Android 3.x and newer

Comment: what should I do then

Comment: service started in another process should remain alive in that case

Comment: First, why is your app force stopped? By the user or by Android OS? If by Android OS you can do some other tricks to maximize the duration of a Service for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest - i.e, static receiver but in fact you do not have such a class and you are creating a dynamic receiver in your activity.

What you are actually doing is registering your receiver when your activity starts, but you want the other way around (start your activity/app once the receiver receives a broadcast).
You need to create a class which is called `SMSbr extends BroadcastReceiver` and there you can  perform your logics.
That way you will have the receiver always registered and when an SMS broadcast will be received it will wake your app.